# C++ bad-alloc error

Tags: c++, vector, bad-alloc, large-data

I need to find all-pair distances for a dataset of 10000 points. I am coding in C++ using vector for storing the points. This is my vector:

```
vector <vector <double> > data.
vector <vector <double> > dist.
```

I am reading input data from a file and storing in data. Then i compute all pair distances and store it in dist.

It works fine for small dataset upto 8000 points. But when i run the same code for larger dataset, i am getting the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>
> what():  std::bad_alloc
>
> Aborted (core dumped).

I have surfed the net, but could not find the solution. Please help me how to fix this.

Comment: In case of 8000 points, you have vectors of 64 millions doubles, which takes at least 512MB per vector. Perhaps you are running out of memory with large data sets.

Comment: Operating system don't want to give your program more memory. Likely because you consumed way too much.

Comment: How many double do you have for each point of the data set? It's clear that you are running out of memory. The questions you have to ask yourself: Am I using more memory than I need? Is there a way to capture the data with less memory?

Comment: Are you running at 32 bits?

Answer (score 0):

You are using too much memory, and it seems the vector is unable to allocate this memory.

As above mentioned there's ~512 MB memory per vector if you take into account only the doubles (the std::vector class also have some internal variables and vfptable , which you allocate 8000 times).

the std:vector has the habbit of increasing it's size each time you go over it's pre-allocated limit, to prevent reallocs on each new element added which are expensive .

So the vector's true size will always be bigger then the number of elements from inside it.

Try managing your own memory for such big numbers, especially if you know from the start the number of elements.

std:vector is very useful when you don't know how many elements will be added, ande definately not for sizes of 64 million elements :).